# Anime where someone gets killed by a gelatinous blob onboard a spacecraft and the crew jettisons their corpse into outer space

Tags: story-identification, anime, spaceship, space

This was a VHS my sister and her friends had rented at a local movie rental store, whoever was in charge had great taste in anime and always carried a decent selection, the anime in question definitely would have been released prior to the year 2000. No telling if it was a series or a standalone movie.  The only thing I remember about it is that a member of the crew gets killed by being absorbed by a gelatinous blob onboard a spacecraft and the crew ends up jettisoning their corpse into outer space.  I tried tipofmytongue.reddit.com and had no success.

Comment: Are you sure it was gelatinous blob? How many crew members were there? What sort of anime animation? Because that sounds like Lily  C.A.T (1987) . See if this rings any bells: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0QgGsnN-8g